# Nvidia GeForce 930M driver and PCI bus error on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-14.04, pci-express, nvidia-geforce

I bought a new laptop ASUS-X556UF and installed ubuntu 14.04 in it. Now i was trying to install Nvidia drivers://elementaryforums.com/index.php?threads/howto-install-latest-nvidia-driver-on-linux-without-getting-black-screen.7/ link to install it .

At this point i noticed the problem with my system. When i switched to command line mode ( Ctrl+ALT+f1) there was continuous error display on my console.So i accessed my syslog to verify it. The same error was flushing my /var/log/syslog file. Below is the error i got :-

```
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993338] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993342] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993351] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993700] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.993723] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994075] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994078] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994080] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error        
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994090] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994439] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994464] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994816] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994818] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994820] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994829] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e5
Mar 20 05:27:41 Asus-X556UF kernel: [  615.994837] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e5(Receiver ID)
```

So tried to search with what device my PCI bus 'ic' was connected and thus i ran below command :-

```
$ lspci -v -s 1c.0 | grep Bus:
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
$ lspci -s 1:0
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930M]
```

It was connected to my graphics card. I don't what causing this problem. Is it because of driver or something else .

I also tried to install the propriety driver in ubuntu through additional drivers tab . But what i got is the black screen at login screen.

Please let me know what causing the error and also help to install nvidia driver and use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has been posted a while ago, this other post might be useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/771899/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected

The error is related to the device on pcieport 0000:00:1c.5 which usually are used by network devices, not the NVIDIA video card as you said, which is actually connected to the pcieport 0000:01:00.0

Apparently the PCIe Bus Error is a bug related to

> "(...) the recent Intel Skylake architecture CPUs and Realtek rtl8723be
>   wireless adaptor."

as stated in the post I linked.

You can disable the error messages or the MSI for now until someone fixes it. It's also explained in the post I linked.

Good luck!